# Does anyone know how to run a method form a other class when button is clicked in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

```
  public class HelpMe{

      GUI window = new GUI();
      // Some code
      public void MyFunction(){
      //Some code
      }
}
```

In the GUI class I have a button whit a Action Listener to do something(that part works), so I what to run `MyFunction()` when the button is clicked. Is that possible. Or do I have to do a interface and override that function or something. Thank you in advance

Comment: Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: How does the GUI class instance get a reference to the HelpMe class's instance?  It needs that reference to call HelpMe's methods.  Note: MyFunction needs a return type to be a correctly coded method.

Comment: Yes, that is that I want to find out. Do I interface and just override the function in GUI class, will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understand that you want is something like this.

I have used two methods, one normal and the other using lambda expressions. I hope this helps.

```java
package cl.lherrera;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //lambdaApproach();
        statedApproach();

    }

    public static void externalMethod() {
        System.out.println("KEY PRESSED !!");

    }


    public static void statedApproach() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Aplication name");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton myButton = new JButton("Push me");
        panel.add(myButton);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        ActionListener myEvent = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Main.externalMethod();

            }

        };

        myButton.addActionListener(myEvent);

    }

    public static void lambdaApproach() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Aplication name");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton myButton = new JButton("Push me");
        panel.add(myButton);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        myButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> Main.externalMethod());

    }


}
```

Comment: I have implemented that part in `GUI` class and it works. So I want to run `MyFunction()` instead of `System.out.println("KEY PRESSED !!");` when the button is pushed. Thanks Anyway

Comment: THANK YOU LUIS! What a GOAT!!